# How current can flow through open circuit output and 9v across diode?

Tags: diodes

[image],how voltage across diode can be greater than 0.7 volts in forward bias

Comment: Hint: it says that the output voltage needs to be 9 V. Nowhere does it state what the polarity of Vo should be. When can there be more than 0.7 V across a diode?

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it

Comment: I read the question as saying there is 20 V across the input terminals.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie If I understand your hint correctly the polarity of Vo is such that the cathode of diode is + 9V higher than its anode, how can the diode **forward** current be 1.5 mA or higher?

Comment: @Chu How do you read 20V? I read it as: the input can be +10V or -10V (AC source?) or: the input is about 10V. Were it an AC source, the peak-to-peak may be 20V, but voltage the circuit will see will never exceed 10V or subceed -10V, so, surely not 20 V across the input terminals.

Comment: @Huisman To have 9 V at the output the diode must be in reverse mode so that's what I assumed. Then indeed Vo = 9 V with the + at the diode's cathode. I didn't pay attention to the stated forward currents. Now that I do, **they make no sense**. There is something weird going on in this question.

Comment: @Huisman the differential supply voltage of an op amp is given as \$\pm 15V\$ for example.And that maybe why the possible resistance values are \$1k\$ and \$10k\$. If Vi = 20V, then the required resistance is 10k

Comment: Image looks like a copy of a copy, poor typesetting, bad punctuation, diode has lean on it etc. Where did this question come from ?

Answer (score 1):

> C) 1k, 9.3mA

To get this answer we must assume that the 9V 1mA output and the diode forward current are occurring with opposite input polarities (ie. not at the same time). This is the only way the question makes sense because the circuit cannot put out 9V when the polarity is positive, while the diode can't draw current when it is negative.

First calculation:-

Vin = -10V, Vout = -9V and Iout =-1mA.

R1 = (10V-9V)/1mA = 1kΩ.

Second calculation:-

Vin = +10V. Diode Vf = ~0.7V.

Diode current = (10-0.7)/1kΩ = 9.3mA.

This assumes that the load is not applied when positive voltage is applied, or that it draws insignificant current at 0.7V.

Comment: That’s what I figured out in my head +1

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers make sense.

Would the diode be in reverse-biased, the voltage could become (minus) 9 V.
There is still a current flowing in reverse mode, but that current is called *reverse current* or *leakage current*, not forward current.
This reverse current typically is in the order of nA to uA.

Would the diode be in forward mode, **the voltage can exceed 0.7 V** (to address you main question), check the graphs of the 1N4148 from Vishay below, but that would require a forward current that is typically in the order of A, not mA as given in the answers.
But a forward voltage of 9 V is very unlikely.

[image]

**Regarding the answers themselves:**
The question states the output current is approx 1 mA. This current plus the diode **forward** current flows through the resistor R1.
For the given answers, this means a voltage drop across R1 of:

$$ \text{ A) } V_{R1} = 1k\Omega \cdot (6+1)\text{ mA} = 7 \text{ V} $$
$$ \text{ B) } V_{R1} = 10k\Omega \cdot (3+1)\text{ mA} = 40 \text{ V} $$
$$ \text{ C) } V_{R1} = 1k\Omega \cdot (9.3+1)\text{ mA} = 10.3 \text{ V} $$
$$ \text{ D) } V_{R1} = 10k\Omega \cdot (1.5+1)\text{ mA} = 25 \text{ V} $$

Subtracting any of these voltage drops from the input voltage, be it 10 V or 20 V, will never give an output voltage of 9 V.
(Maybe answer C comes closest using 20 V input voltage and 1.7 mA output current, but then, I would define 1.7 mA output current as approximately **2** mA instead of 1 mA.)

But for all these answers, still, a forward voltage of 9 V still is unrealistic.